# Instagram notification: "X, who you may know, is on Instagram. Would you like to follow them?"

Tags: facebook, notifications, instagram, facebook-notifications

For the last month or so, Instagram has been *frequently* sending me the following push notifications:

---

[image: Instagram "may know" notification]

> - USER, who you may know, is on Instagram. Would you like to follow them?
> - USER, who you might know, is on Instagram.
> - USER is on Instagram. USER2 and X others also follow them.
> - Since you follow USER1, you might like USER2.
> - Follow USER1, USER2, and others you know to see their photos and videos.

---

The account is *never* someone "I may know" in real life, so it does not seem to be based on a Facebook link or Contact / Phone Number. It seems to be based on Instagram interests / in-common followers / similar accounts.

I have always had almost every notification setting turned OFF in `Settings > Notifications`. This must be a new notification type that Facebook/Instagram has added to their "growth hack" list and helpfully turned ON by default.

Which **specific Notification Setting** controls these "who you may know" notifications? How can I stop seeing these notifications?

---

Discussed elsewhere:

- [Reddit search for these alerts](https://old.reddit.com/r/Instagram/search/?q=%22might+know%22+OR+%22may+know%22&sort=new&restrict_sr=on&t=all)
- [Twitter search of people complaining about this notification type](https://twitter.com/search?q=(%22you%20might%20know%22%20OR%20%22you%20may%20know%22)%20(instagram%20OR%20insta%20OR%20ig)&src=typed_query&f=live)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings → Notifications → Following and Followers → Account Suggestions → Off.

Comment: Note: this setting does now control iOS push notifications, but the messages still seem to appear in your in-app Activity feed even after turning them `Off`.

Answer (score 1):

These have been annoying me as well. Unfortunately, you can't turn these off. You would have to turn off all Instagram notifications to get rid of it.